# "Cannot reach this page" npm start

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, npm-scripts

Everything was working well enough before I ran `npm start` the last time to see my web page in the browser. The issue that I started to encounter repeatedly is-

Firstly, it takes more than 2 minutes to show ***"starting the development server"*** and then after taking the same amount of time, all I see is ***"Cannot reach this page"***. And that's not all. My whole system hangs there. I can't do anything. Not even the mouse moves.

I re-setup `create-react-app` thrice, but with the same result. Then I tried `npm start` on one of my other projects on my system and it worked normally.

I can't suspect my current project setup because this was working all well before this issue arised out of nowhere. Please have a look at the project- [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/project1-piltz?file=/package.json)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem lies in `Downloads-Section.scss` where there is an infinite loop, since `$i` never gets incremented. This results in an infinitely long css file compilation which in turn uses too much memory leading to a system shutdown.

The easiest fix is to use a for instead, since this reduces the chances of this happening again:

```
        @for $i from 1 through 4 {
            .card#{$i} {
                grid-area: card#{$i};
            }
        }
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/project1-3g45p?file=/src/comps/download-section/Download-section.scss:367-444

Comment: Also you have a text encoding issue in the `Join-section.jsx`

Comment: I can't believe it! How could I miss out on that! It wasted a half of my day. :-( Thanks for digging deep into the bug!

Comment: Actually didn't take long as Safari pointed out that it was taking "Significant Memory"

Comment: oh you mean the '+' symbol?

Comment: Just realized I misunderstood your question - The text encoding is in `Weâre` (shows `â€ ` on my computer) which is a code-point encoding being interpreted as UTF-8 as far as I can tell

Comment: Honestly, I don't see anything wrong - Then again I don't have access to Edge right now. Safari and Chrome work fine with only minimal errors